# How can I update SHA1s within commit messages after a rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

Consider this history:

```
E  BUG: fix regression in <sha-1 of C>
|
D  fixup! Do a thing
|
C  Add a feature
|
B  Do a thing
|
A  Initial commit
```

Is there a variant of `git rebase -i --autosquash` that will adjust the commit message of E to match the following?

```
E'  BUG: fix regression in <sha-1 of C'>
|
C'  Add a feature
|
BD' Do a thing
|
A   Initial commit
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't really think of an *automated* way.  In an interactive rebase, you could mark commit `E` for either "reword" or "edit" and change the SHA yourself.  (I think "edit" might be easier simply so that you could use `log` to find the correct SHA to fill in before kicking off the commit message editor.)

**UPDATE**

Bringing in some thoughts from the comments:  If you're dealing with a rewrite of a large history with many such references, such that an interactive rebase with manual message edits is unrealistic, it's quite a lot harder to envision a solution.

While your question seems to focus on `rebase`, in comments you mention you might really be thinking of a `filter-branch`.  (Which, it should be noted, is a very different operation, so that it's almost never easy to substitute one for the other...)

Your best bet in any case is to rewrite the commit messages in the same operation that caused the commit SHA values to change.  (If you try to do it "after the fact", then the rewrite of a commit `X`'s message will *again* change the SHA of not only `X`, but also any commits that reaches `X` via parent pointers; so you'll have to keep track of / work through multiple ID mappings at that point.)

In theory what you want is a `msg-filter` that does `sed`-type search-and-replace on the SHA values; but the trouble is where you get the "old sha to new sha" mapping.

There is a shell function `map`, which torek indicates can be of some help, at least from within the filter scripts.  (The docs I found only confirm this to be available during execution of the `commit-filter`, but if torek says the other filters can see it then I'm inclined to think he's right. The question would be whether that might change in a future version, if indeed it's undocumented.  If this worries you, you could shoe-horn the message edit into a commit filter, maybe...)

So you could write a script that looks at the old commit message (received on STDIN if you stick with `msg-filter`) and searches it for possible SHA values (strings of 40 characters in [0-9a-f]). On finding a possible value, it would call `map` and, if `map` returns what looks like a single SHA value, edit the message text.  Then return the edited text on STDOUT.  (But: I believe that will only work if you actually have the full 40-character SHA in your commit messages.  If you abbreviate, that's another can of worms...)

(Note that `map` *can* return multiple SHA values, but the only case I've found for this is if you were doing something exotic with the `commit-filter`.)

Comment: I'm envisaging a large rebase, possibly of the `filter-branch` variety, where doing this manually would be impractical.

Comment: Then you'll probably need custom tooling.  What you're describing is not simple at all.  If you're already looking at `filter-branch`, you could use a `msg-filter`.  But you'd have to build up an "old-SHA-to-new-SHA" mapping as each commit rewrite occurs, and then the filter would be a script (I'd go with perl personally) that could search-and-replace through the commit message based on the contents of the mapping.  This assumes that any commit `T` is reachable (by parent pointers) from a commit `S` whose commit message references `T`, so that you'd know `S` was rewritten before `T`

Comment: To be clear - I'm not sure how you would build the old-SHA-to-new-SHA mapping incrementally and am not sure it's even possible from within a run of `filter-branch`

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: `git filter-branch` has in its shell code a `map` function that does the translation from original hash to copied hash. As either a missing feature or a bug, filter-branch fails to provide any way to *export* the map (necessary for fixing up `git notes` or doing submodule tricks, for instance), but it's available until the thing finishes. It's a pain to use from a script as `map` itself is only available in the `eval`ed filters. Rebase also builds such a map and runs `git notes copy`, but lacks a way to let you work with this map while you rebase.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, @torek. So the `map` function takes an "old" SHA and returns a "new" one? In which case you'd almost have to scan the message for possible SHA values, on finding one feed it to the function, and (iff it returns a sensible result) proceed to edit the message?  I guess  that's not the *worst* thing I've heard of...

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: More precisely, `map` takes an old hash and returns *one or more* new ones, depending on your filters. It's actually just `cat`ing a file (one per commit!) that filter-branch creates/updates. If you filter 100k commits you get 100k of these map files in one directory, which most OSes handle poorly, which is one reason (of many) that filter-branch is slow.